# How to contain a video?

Tags: html, css, video, size

Quick question since I can't find it here.
I have a video and I have attached it with the following code on html

```css
video {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div class="banner-header">
    <video poster="#" autoplay="true" loop>
      <source src="coding.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
```

When I try it out, my video shows, it plays and loops. Perfect. Except the size is so massive that I can scroll to the right and I no longer see the body just the background and the far right side of the video.

I want the video to be smaller and to align properly with the whole responsive website. And below the video is pretty much the body of the website, which are my skills and contact details. So the video serves as a "header" even though I have a proper header with navigation buttons and what not.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, remove

```
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

then specify a numerical value for `width`, for example `50%` or `400px`.

The browser will proportionally scale the video, so you don't need to set the height.

Comment: CORRECTION, yes it made the video smaller width wise, however the background for that section still covered the original size (which is so massive width wise)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

On my CSS I had the following code

```
    .banner {
  width: 150%;
  background-color: #6991AC;
}
```

changed it from 150% to 100%, with the CSS code for video from the question I changed it to only contain width and height, with width set to 100% and height to auto.